# stripping of white spaces from a string

Tags: c++, boost, tokenize, strip

I have the following string

```
argsStr = "server ('m1.labs.terada')ta.com') username ('user5') password('user)5') dbname ('default')";
```

I want to extract the argument name i.e "server" "username" "password".

I am using the following regex to do that

```
boost::regex re1("\\(\'[!-~]+\'\\)");
boost::sregex_token_iterator x(argsStr.begin(), argsStr.end(), re1, -1),x1;   boost::sregex_token_iterator y;
std::copy(x, x1, std::back_inserter(v2));
```

v2 is string vector, where I am extracting the tokens. However, The tokens I am getting are

```
"server "    INSTEAD of "server
" username "  INSTEAD of "username".
```

How shall I remove these white spaces?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use [boost string algorithms](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#idp424359600)

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

std::string str("hello world! ");
boost::trim_right(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove white spaces from a string using this:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string/erase.hpp>

str.erase(remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), ::isspace),str.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a couple of `"\s*"` to your regexp:

```
std::regex re1(R"(\s*\('[!-~]+'\)\s*)");
std::sregex_token_iterator x(argsStr.begin(), argsStr.end(), re1, -1), x1;   
std::copy(x, x1, std::back_inserter(v2));
```

`\s` stands for "whitespace character".
This will leave the leftmost whitespace where it is though - if you want to account for that, you can alter the range:

```
std::string::iterator start = std::find_if_not(argsStr.begin(), argsStr.end(), ::isspace);
std::sregex_token_iterator x(start, argsStr.end(), re1, -1), x1;
```

I used `std::regex` in this example but it works for boost as well. Also I used [raw string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) for readability, if it is even a thing for regular expressions.